# Rasterio - Extract raster pixel values based on another raster's pixel values

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, extract-by-mask

I have two single band rasters, both with the same spatial resolution and CRS. A land cover raster (named `clc`), and another one, that is for a smaller area (named `patch`) and falls within the extent of `clc`. Here are some details of the two rasters:

|  | `clc` | `patch` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Number of Bands | 1 | 1 |
| CRS | EPSG:32632 | EPSG:32632 |
| Spatial resolution | (60.0, 60.0) | (60.0, 60.0) |
| Rows | 14452 | 135 |
| Columns | 12067 | 134 |

I want to extract a new raster with the extent and pixel values of `patch` on the locations where `clc` has values defined in a list [10, 13, 22].

I am new to rasterio and only managed to extract the `clc` values instead of the corresponding `patch` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to create a boolean array where `clc` values are *not* in `[10, 13, 22]` and use that to mask `patch` with `nodata`.  This means you will retain only `patch` values where `clc` values are in `[10, 13, 22]`.

As your clc raster is larger, you'll need to read only from a [window matching the bounds](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.from_bounds) (extent) of the patch raster:

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.windows import from_bounds

with rio.open('patch.tif') as patch:
    patchdata = patch.read()
    profile = patch.profile.copy()
    bounds = patch.bounds

with rio.open('clc.tif') as clc:
    window = from_bounds(*bounds, clc.transform)
    clcdata = clc.read(window=window)

# create bool array where clc is not in list of values
mask = np.isin(clcdata, [10, 13, 22], invert=True)

# replace None with lowest value in dtype range
if profile["nodata"] is None:
    profile["nodata"] = np.iinfo(patchdata.dtype).min


# set everything where mask is True to NoData
patchdata[mask] = profile["nodata"]

with rio.open('output.tif', "w", **profile) as output:
    output.write(patchdata)
```

Comment: Thaanks for your response. I receive an error

"IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 135 but corresponding boolean dimension is 14452"

Does that mean that I have to limit the operation to the extent of patch?

Comment: Yes, both arrays have to be the same shape.  You neglected to mention that they differed in your question. Please [edit it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/451334/edit) to specify the no of rows, cols and bands in each raster.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my original question. Do you happen to know a method to do this?

Comment: That's great, I did something similar in the end but your way has fewer lines. I also added a condition to replace None values with 0, because otherwise it throws an error. Thank you so much for your time.